# Multivariate deterministic regression imputation via mice leads to unstable results

Tags: r, missing-data, deterministic, imputation, r-mice

The `mice` R package provides deterministic regression imputation by specifying `method = "norm.predict"`. Due to the nature of deterministic regression imputation, i.e. no noise is added to imputed values, I would expect that imputed values are always the same, no matter which seed I use. With univariate missings, this seems to work. However, I found inconsistencies when I am imputing multivariate missings. Below, the problem is illustrated with a reproducible example:

```
library("mice")

# Example 1: Univariate missings (works fine)
data1 <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 8, 5, 1, 7, 4),
                    x2 = c(2, 13, 12, 5, 6, 6, 1, 2),
                    x3 = c(4, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 7, 3))

# Impute univariate missings
imp <- mice(data1, method = "norm.predict", m = 1)
complete(imp) # Always the same result


# Example 2: Multivariate missings (leads to inconsistent imputations)
data2 <- data1
data2[4, 2] <- NA

# Impute multivariate missings
imp1 <- mice(data2, method = "norm.predict", m = 1, seed = 111)
imp2 <- mice(data2, method = "norm.predict", m = 1, seed = 222)

# Results are different
complete(imp1)
complete(imp2)
```

**Question: Why are multivariate deterministic regression imputations by mice inconsistent?**

Comment: To be sure, your question is "Why the `seed` parameter of the `mice()` function doesn't work properly?". Seems a bug to me.

Comment: @F.Privé No, my question is: Why are the imputed values different, when I use different seeds? If I understood correctly, there is no randomness involved in deterministic regression imputation. For that reason, I would expect that the seed does not influence the imputed values. In the example above, however, the results are dependent on the seed. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?mice` have a look at the description of the data.init argument:

> **data.init**  A data frame of the same size and type as data, without
>   missing data, used to initialize imputations before the start of the
>   iterative process. **The default NULL implies that starting imputation
>   are created by a simple random draw from the data**. Note that
>   specification of data.init will start the m Gibbs sampling streams
>   from the same imputations.

This is where the randomness comes from. Not from the norm.predict method itself, which, as you say, is completely deterministic. (you can see the method to confirm this by typing `mice.impute.norm.predict` at the console).

So to avoid the random sampling, we have to provide `mice` with `data.init`:

```
data.init = data2
for (i in 1:ncol(data.init)) data.init[, i][is.na(data.init[, i])] = 1

imp1 <- mice(data2, method = "norm.predict", m = 1, data.init = data.init, seed = 111)
imp2 <- mice(data2, method = "norm.predict", m = 1, data.init = data.init, seed = 222)

# Results are the same
complete(imp1)
complete(imp2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this perfect answer!